# Special characters - String - Binary - Java

Tags: string, binary, special-characters

I tried to convert a String to binary and back. It works very well, but if I have a special character, like €, in the String it gives me a questionmark back. How can I solve this?

This is my Code for converting a String to binary:

```
// stringToBinary
public static String stringToBinary(String message) {
    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int val = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
        }
        binary.append(' ');
    }
    return binary.toString();
}
```

And I use this Code for doing it the other way around with each "block":

```
// binaryToChar
public static char binaryToChar(String block) {
    int ascii = Integer.parseInt(block, 2);
    return (char) ascii;
}
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

EDIT: I found € in this list: [>>Klick<<](http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp)
So it is right, that € is displayed as `10000000` in binary, but it isn't shown as this after reconverting to a String/char.

Comment: What do you call a "special character"? Anything not in the ASCII set? Anything with a value above 255?

Comment: I edited my question a second ago :D

Comment: Okay, I think I see the problem. Can you check what numeric value your Euro character is converted to in Java? (You have to check. There are some variants possible but I think Java defaults to UTF8 or Unicode.)

Comment: It is converted to `10000000`. It is also not working with characters like 中 or 漢 @Jongware

Comment: That is unexpected - it's either some local encoding or an error in your code. It's nothing near what I described as [possible values above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm). This needs to be looked at by someone with more Java experience.

Comment: Okay but thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I can answer my own question :O

I edited my Code a Little bit and tried some Things and now this works:

```
// stringToBinary
public static String stringToBinary(String message) {
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : message.toCharArray()) {
        int i = (int) c;
        binary.append(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        binary.append(' ');
    }
    return binary.toString();
}
```

Thanks to everyone who thought about my question :)